# ASP.NET SQL Server state management - get appid

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, state-management

I am using SQL Server for state management for my ASP.NET application.

In the table `ASPStateTempSessions`, there is `sessionid` column which is `sessionid + appid`. I want to know how can I determine the `appid`?

Answer (score 0):

I think the app ID is the one from the ASPStateTempSessions table, which is created by aspnet_regsql.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the TempGetAppID sproc. read up on it **[HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd942394.aspx)**

you can get the appname from :System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ApplicationName

That should give you the AppID